# Are all countable dense subsets of the real line of this form?

Tags: real-analysis

Are all countable dense subsets of the real line of this form?:
$$E_c = \{x + c \mid x \in \mathbb{Q} \} \cup D - F $$

Where $c$ is some real number and $D$ and $F$ are nowhere dense sets. So, informally, they are the rationals shifted horizontally modulus some nowhere dense set. If so, how to prove it? If not, show a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the set $\{x\sqrt{2}\mid x\in\Bbb Q\}$ of this form?

Comment: Good, I forgot expansions and contractions. If I changed it to $E_{a,b} = \{ ax + b \}$ modulus nowhere dense sets would that characterize all of them?

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to me these sets could have less regular structure. Think on images of $\Bbb Q$ by some bijection diferent from the affine form. So, what about $\{\sqrt{2}x^3\mid x\in\Bbb Q\}$?

Answer (score 1):

All countable dense sets of $\Bbb R$ are homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, because they're countable metric and have no isolated points. See [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf) on this classical (1920) theorem by Sierpiński.